# My template if used in angular doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I've a template that if used in django works fine, but now that I'm starting  using angular I have many problems with the animations, for example when I click on this simple button in django

```
<div class="m-login__form-action">
   <button type="button" id="m_login_signup" class="btn btn-outline-focus m-btn--pill">Crea un Account</button>
</div>
```

It animated a moving page and then it shows me a different page to sign up, but in angular, when I click on the same button I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined
at Object.one (scripts.bundle.js:1)
at Object.animateClass (scripts.bundle.js:1)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (login.js:1)
at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (vendors.bundle.js:1)
at HTMLButtonElement.g.handle (vendors.bundle.js:1)
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:498)
at invokeTask (zone.js:1744)
at HTMLButtonElement.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone.js:1770)
```

Probably I didn't import something in the module or in the component, but I can't figure out why..
Is it possible that this error has something to do with jquery?

I'd like to specify that some other animated components work.
If you need any other file please tell me, thankyou!

login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/auth.service'
import { Router, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent{

  loginForm: FormGroup;
  errorMessage: string = '';
  registerForm: FormGroup;
  successMessage: string = '';

  constructor(
    public authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.createForm();
  }
tryLogin(value){
    console.log(value);
    this.authService.doLogin(value)
    //.then(res => {
    //  this.router.navigate(['/user']);
    //}, err => {
    //  console.log(err);
    //  this.errorMessage = err.message;
    //})
  }
  tryRegister(value){
     this.authService.doRegister(value)
     .then(res => {
       console.log(res);
       this.errorMessage = "";
       this.successMessage = "Your account has been created";
     }, err => {
       console.log(err);
       this.errorMessage = err.message;
       this.successMessage = "";
     })
   }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";


import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { MissionComponent } from './mission/mission.component';
import { MaterialComponent } from './material/material.component';
import { BinComponent } from './bin/bin.component';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';
import { ScriptLoaderService } from "./_services/script-loader.service";


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    MissionComponent,
    MaterialComponent,
    BinComponent,
    UserComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,

  ],
  providers: [ScriptLoaderService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Update Stackblitz** 
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vcpzn7)

Comment: Can you share the code of your ts file?

Comment: You are going to have to share more code because that html as it is now isolated in an angular app won't do anything and also not cause an exception. Please create an [mcve], I recommend https://stackblitz.com

Comment: I've update my code, now i'll create a stackblitz

Comment: @DmitryS. @Igor i've created a stackbliz but i'm getting an error `turbo_modules`